# Google Play Console Statistics When Developing an Application

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm developing an application on Android Studios that is already linked to the Google Play Console.  During development, I am constantly uninstalling and reinstalling my application and writing experimental code that at times crashes my app.  These crash statistics seem to show up on the google play console statistics.  Could someone verify if that is indeed correct?  Also does the uninstall count get ticked up every time I uninstall the application from my phone during development?

I hope my question is clear, haven't been able to find anything that speaks specifically to whether or not statistics are affected when developing an Application on android studios that is already linked to the play store.

I'd be happy to clarify anything that is unclear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installs and uninstalls from Google Play will still count. Installs and Uninstalls from Android Studio don't.

Crash statistics from Android Studio installs do show up right now, but should stop soon - this is an error in the Play console.